# Find duplicates in MYSQL

Tags: mysql

I have a table which records the user logged in against the time. I need to generate a report to display number of times an user logged in in each month. How do i do this ?

--Edit--
I could print each user appearing X times in a month that is ok for me. But i want to display a monthly list showing number of person logged in 5 times in a month.

Comment: How are you recording the time, hopefully a DateTime type?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

from the comments: "i want to display how many users logged in more than 5 times"

```
SELECT YearMonth, COUNT(User)
FROM (
  SELECT
    User
  , DATE_FORMAT(LoggedInTime, '%Y-%m') As YearMonth
  FROM user_logins
  GROUP BY User, YearMonth
  HAVING COUNT(*) > 5
)GROUP BY YearMonth
```

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT
  User
, DATE_FORMAT(LoggedInTime, '%Y-%m') As YearMonth
, COUNT(*) AS NumLogins
FROM user_logins
GROUP BY User, YearMonth
```

Comment: grouping by 2 columns will show me the number of times a particular user logged in a month. BUt i want to display how many users logged in more than 5 times in a particular time.. got it ??

Answer (score 1):

the main option available here for you (IMO) is to count the times a user appears in a group per month like so:

```
SELECT user_id,
       count(datetime) as logins, 
       MONTH(datetime) as month 
FROM table
GROUP BY 1, 3
```

for date and time functions in mysql check the manual [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html)